# Infinite ads load stops Ruby script

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, selenium, capybara

I am trying to make a simple script using ruby/capybara (with firefox).
It opens a site that has some kind of ads with bugs (loading infinitely) and the script stops.
How can I stop this loading?

Comment: Please provide us snippets of where you think the issue can be & what you have tried to fix.

Answer (score 0):

To block specific browser requests, when using Firefox through selenium with Capybara, you will need a programmable proxy.  One option for this is [puffing-billy](https://github.com/oesmith/puffing-billy)